# Wacom tablet pen drawing while hovering

Tags: tablet, pen

I have the Wacom Intuos and whenever I try to draw on FireAlpaca it draws even when I hover over the tablet with my pen. I don't know if it's something to do with my pen or the tablet, so if you know how to fix it please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You shold try the tablet with the pen on other programs or also like a mouse. 
If it works, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn8KpOm1IQ0) is a basic tutorial for FireAlpaca.